# Por que println executou antes que printStackTace?

Tags: java, exceção, console

Estava estudando Tratamento de Exceções em Java e me veio essa dúvida que não soube achar no Google.

Por que neste exemplo ele printou a primeira linha do printStackTrace, e já deu o println, e depois o resto do printStackTrace?

[image: Exemplo de Código]

Comment: Quando vc loga muitas coisas ao mesmo tempo (Sei que no seu caso foi apenas uma instrução), pode acontecer de uma mensagem "atravessar" a outra...

Comment: Olha essa pergunta http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19460987/why-is-system-out-prinln-out-of-order

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A princípio um sistema operacional trabalha com 3 filas `System.err` *(saida de fluxo para erro padrão stderr)*, `System.out` *(saida de fluxo padrao stdout)* e `System.in` *(entrada de dados stdin)*

Ao utilizar o `PrintStackTrace`, ele escreve por padrão em `System.err` e também informa um rastreamento de pilha, ou seja, a cadeia de métodos que levou a excepção.

Em um aplicativo de console Java simples, ambas as saídas (`System.err` e `System.out`) serão as mesmas (console da aplicação) mas você pode reconfigurar os fluxos para por exemplo `System.out` imprimir no console e `System.err` gravar em um arquivo por exemplo.

Com relação a ordem, ambos executam na mesma sequencia, porém o sistema operacional pode escolher aleatoriamente qual fila imprimir primeiro (`stderr` ou `stdout`).

por exemplo

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("stdout -> 1");
    System.out.println("stdout -> 2");
    System.out.println("stdout -> 3");
    System.err.println("stderr -> 1");
    System.err.println("stderr -> 2");
    System.err.println("stderr -> 3");
}
```

neste trecho de código faço o envio de 3 instruções para stdout e 3 para stderr,
elas serão executadas em sequencia, porém cada fila pode assumir ordem aleatória pelo SO.

Você verá que a cada execução ele vai mudar a ordem das filas porém a ordem de instruções para a fila não, a impressão para `stdout` respeitará a sequencia (1, 2, 3) e para `stderr` também (1, 2, 3) porém a ordem que ele vai exibir a fila não irá respeitar esta sequencia (stdout, stderr)

Existe uma forma de sincronizar as duas filas, porém é uma espécie de hack:

```
public class ConsoleHackTools {

    private static OutputStream lastStream = null;
    private static boolean isFixed = false;

    private static class FixedStream extends OutputStream {

        private final OutputStream target;

        public FixedStream(OutputStream originalStream) {
            target = originalStream;
        }

        @Override
        public void write(int b) throws IOException {
            if (lastStream != this)
                swap();
            target.write(b);
        }

        @Override
        public void write(byte[] b) throws IOException {
            if (lastStream != this)
                swap();
            target.write(b);
        }

        @Override
        public void write(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
            if (lastStream != this)
                swap();
            target.write(b, off, len);
        }

        private void swap() throws IOException {
            if (lastStream != null) {
                lastStream.flush();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(200);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }
            lastStream = this;
        }

        @Override
        public void close() throws IOException {
            target.close();
        }

        @Override
        public void flush() throws IOException {
            target.flush();
        }
    }

    public static void fixConsole() {
        if (isFixed)
            return;
        isFixed = true;
        System.setErr(new PrintStream(new FixedStream(System.err)));
        System.setOut(new PrintStream(new FixedStream(System.out)));
    }
}
```

Com esse hack, mudando o exemplo de sysout e syserr anterior ficaria da seguinte maneira:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ConsoleHackTools.fixConsole();

    System.out.println("stdout -> 1");
    System.out.println("stdout -> 2");
    System.out.println("stdout -> 3");
    System.err.println("stderr -> 1");
    System.err.println("stderr -> 2");
    System.err.println("stderr -> 3");
}
```

Neste código, você verá que agora sim a aplicação vai respeitar a sequencia stdout (1, 2, 3), stderr (1, 2, 3) e também a sequencia das filas (stdout, stderr)

Comment: O fato de ás vezes uma mensagem "atravessar a outra" no console significa que há alguma espécie de concorrência entre Threads quando o S.O. vai imprimir no console? Por exemplo, ele pode tentar imprimir mensagens de filas diferentes ao mesmo tempo e embaralha-las? É isso que ocorre?

Comment: isto, digamos que cada fila (StdOut e StdErr) são processadas em threads diferentes, pode acontecer de a thread do StdOut escrever no console ao mesmo tempo que o StdErr está escrevendo ou ao contrário, esse gerenciamento fica por conta do SO, ou atravez do hack acima, basicamente este "hack" tenta deixar a acao destas duas threads na jvm "Sincronas"

Comment: Na documentação: ```Optionally, a PrintStream can be created so as to flush automatically; this means that the flush method is automatically invoked after a byte array is written, one of the println methods is invoked, or a newline character or byte ('\n') is written.```

Então a ordem do print vai depender do comportamento do System.out e do System.err na implementação da JVM que você está usando, sem ter muita certeza de quando cada stream vai imprimir. Você pode forçar a impressão imediata chamando o método flush() no out e err

Comment: Faz sentido o que o brow-joe disse, lembrei das aulas de SO que meu professor passou um exercicio de threads para podermos ver que o SO que determina quem vai executar primeiro.

Answer (score 3):

Os sistemas operacionais tem dois streams principais de saídas: saída padrão ou `STDOUT` e erro padrão ou `STDERR` (acessados em java pelos Streams `System.out` e `System.err`). As mensagens de erro, por exemplo o printStackTrace que você usou no código, são impressas no STDERR.

Quando você abre um terminal, por padrão você vê os dois sendo impressos simultaneamente, mas eles são independentes e por isso a ordem que eles são impressos pode variar. Você pode redirecionar as saídas para analisá-las de forma independente.
Por exemplo no Linux, para redicionar a saída padrão para o arquivo `resultado.txt` e o erro padrão para o arquivo `erro.txt`

```
java Metodo1 > resultado.txt 2> erro.txt
```

No arquivo `resultado.txt` eu teria:

```
Acabou o Programa!
```

Já no arquivo `erro.txt`:

```
SenhaInvalidaException: Senha Inválida!
    at Metodo1.autenticar(Metodo1.java:15)
    at Metodo1.main(Metodo1.java:4)
```